# htaccess multiple parameters not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm new with htaccess file, so I'm kindly asking you to help:

In my htaccess file I have next lines:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^alpe-adria(.*)$ site/index.php$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^alpe-adria$ site/index.php?box=1&d=3 [L]
```

So, first I'm trying to set index file, that is in site folder, to show as string above (alpe-adria). Second RewriteRule is my landing page, other pages have same root as seen in the first RewriteRule. When I localy test this rules, my landing page shows as expected (typing localhost/alpe-adria in browser). But then if I want to go to other pages, which have for instance such basic URL:

`http://localhost/site/index.php?d=1&box=1&grp=306&level=1`

RewriteRule acts OK, rewriting this into

'`http://localhost/alpe-adria?d=1&box=1&grp=306&level=1`'

but site stil stays on my landing page - like it is written in second RewriteRule

I was also trying to set some more RewriteCond and adding another RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^alpe-adria?d=([^/]+)&box=([^/]+)&grp=([^/]+)&level=([^/]+)$ site/index.php?d=$1&box=$2&grp=$3&level=$4
```

and site stil doesn't change. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Try to explain it again what exactly are you looking for.

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem with the `.htaccess` not your code? What do you mean that the site doesn't change? Maybe it's something in `index.php` which wrongly recognizes the attributes.

Comment: After  dumping $_GET in my index.php I get same parameters as in my landing page (box=1 and d=3) even if I change url to go to my subpages, which have more parameters.

Case: URL = `http://localhost/alpe-adria?d=1&box=1&grp=3&level=1`

_GET dump -> `array (size=2)
  'box' => string '1' (length=1)
  'd' => string '3' (length=1)`

Comment: I suspect that second RewriteRule overrides other parameters and so it sticks to these parameters, no matter what I change in URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use this rule (without any conditions)?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} box=
RewriteRule ^alpe-adria$ /site/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^alpe-adria$ /site/index.php?box=1&d=3 [L]
```

The query string (everything after the `?`) will automatically get appended to the end if you don't have a `?` in your rule's target. The reason why your rules wasn't working is probably the conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^alpe-adria(.*)$ site/index.php$1 [L]
```

I'm suspecting that you don't actually have a file called "/alpe-adria.php", thus the condition fails, and thus the rule is never applied (otherwise, that one might have worked).

Your second rule, *which has no conditions*, is simply:

```
RewriteRule ^alpe-adria$ site/index.php?box=1&d=3 [L]
```

And this one *doesn't* append the query string, since you are hardcoding it to "box=1" and "d=3".

Comment: After using your first rule - now parameters works only if they are written in url. What I realy want to do is to show my landing page calling only `localhost/alpe-adria` in url (that's why I hardcoded parameters in second rule) and also show other pages, which have parameters - like `localhost/alpe-adria?d=1&box=1&grp=306&level=1`. Problem is that my landing page also needs parameters (box=1&d=3) to show itself in browser. I still cannot figure it out how to combine both rewrite rules

Comment: @user3008034 Ah, I see. See the edit above. The problem is that you can't match against the query string in a rewrite rule, only against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` or `%{THE_REQUEST}` variables

Comment: One more question: how to single out one variable in `%{QUERY_STRING}`, so that I can use another `RewriteRule` for my subpage. I have dificulties to single out parameter `grp`, which is essential to show subapages to landing page. Correct me if I'm wrong, is it true, if I want to single out two parameters, I just need to add two `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` statements, each finding one parameter? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @user3008034 `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)box=([0-9]+)(&|$)` then you can backreference it using `%2` (the [0-9] part)

Comment: And if I want to get exactly one variable from parameter (apart from all other parameters), for example `grp=something`, then I just have to add this `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)grp=something(&|$)`?