# Rewriting url with one parameter out of multiple parameters in .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have next lines in a htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)grp=([0-9]+)(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)level=([0-9]+)(&|$) 
RewriteRule ^alpe-adria/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /site/index.php?d=1&box=1&grp=%1&grpname=$1&level=%2 [L]
```

The original URL has this code:

```
/site/index.php?d=1&box=1&grp=13&grpname=art-culture&level=1
```

The parameters `d` and `box` are fixed, other parameters `grp`, `grpname` and `level` are varying from page to page. What I want to do is to rewrite this URL into such state:

```
/alpe-adria/art-culture
```

So the problem is, how to single out `grpname` parameter and also use all other parameters, from which two are not fixed. I tried two `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` rules with no success. Idea is to single out two parameters and then use them in original URL. In other hand one parameter is used in original URL as in substitute URL. Again, I'm stuck and I need your precious help.

Whole snippet:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} box=
RewriteRule ^alpe-adria$ /site/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} d=
RewriteRule ^alpe-adria$ /site/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} op=
RewriteRule ^alpe-adria$ /site/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} masterSearch=
RewriteRule ^alpe-adria$ /site/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^alpe-adria/?$ /site/index.php?box=1&d=3 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:|.*&)grpname=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^site/index\.php$ /alpe-adria/%1? [L,R]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very clear from your question but you can use a rule like this which makes your capture all these `parameters grp, grpname and level` from anywhere in query string:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+site/index\.php\?d=1&box=1&grp=([^&]*)&grpname=([^&]*)&level=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /alpe-adria/%2/%1/%3? [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^alpe-adria/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /site/index.php?d=1&box=1&grp=$2&grpname=$1&level=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Nice, but is it possible just to redirect into `/alpe-adria/art-culture` without other two parameters?

Comment: Now it shows me 404 error - site not found. Maybe because I have more code in htaccess before this snippet. 
Look at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067729/htaccess-multiple-parameters-not-working - the question I was asking before this problem occured. So, my whole snippet in htaccess file is:

Comment: Edited question above, since code doesn't look good in comments

Comment: Ok I think I got it now. How do you want `/alpe-adria/art-culture` to be handled internally? I believe it would be `/site/index.php` and some query string.

Comment: Indeed, sorry I haven't explained that before. One question: so if I handle it internaly, what will browser see - alpe-adria/art-culture or /site/index.php and some query string?

Comment: browser will only see `/alpe-adria/art-culture`

Comment: I mean what will search engines see, not browsers

Comment: Search engines, browsers or any other web client, all of them will see `/alpe-adria/art-culture`

Comment: So, what options do I have then? I tried now with this: `RewriteRule ^alpe-adria/%1$ /site/index.php [L]`, but with no success. Probably %1 cannot be read from `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:|.*&)grpname=([^&]*)`, if it is put into basic URL pattern.

Comment: I will suggest you the required rule but I just want to know what will be internal URI for `/alpe-adria/art-culture` ?

Comment: internal URI is the same as above: (for now it is localhost)
`http://localhost/alpe-adria?d=1&box=1&grp=13&grpname=art-culture&level=1`

Comment: Oh I thought it would start with `/site/index.php?`

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake :) Yes, it starts with /site/index.php, so true URI is: `http://localhost/site/index.php?d=1&box=1&grp=13&grpname=art-culture&level=1`

Comment: This is OK, but only for `grpname` art-culture. You see, I have different grpnames, which have different `grp` number and different `level` number. For example, I also have `grpname` theatre with `grp` number 33 and `level` number 2, which are different numbers as in solution. I know, I could change RewriteRules for every single `grpname`, but with that I would write many RewriteRules.

Comment: No you should not have that many rewrite rules. But to avoid that you cannot loose vital info while redirecting internal to pretty URI. At present it is: `/alpe-adria/art-culture` which has no info about level. Ideally your pretty URI scheme should be something like: `/alpe-adria/<grp-name>/<grp-num>/<level>` which will be good enough to be rewritten internally to correct URI in single rewrite rule.

Comment: I see, so there unfortunately is no other way. I was asking this simply because of better SEO optimisation, but what the heck, such URI is also good :)

Comment: Yes for any search engine `/alpe-adria/<grp-name>/<grp-num>/<level>` is also pretty good.

Comment: Let me know if you want me to edit the answer on this proposed URI scheme.

Comment: Now it works, only I need to correct CSS, JS and picture paths

Comment: Yes those parts should all be ideally absolute for pry URI schemes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you *really* have such a non-SEO non-SEF URI coming in from a browser? What is the point of converting it to an SEF form like '/alpe-adria/art-culture'? Unless your new directory structure is actually set up that way, and you're trying to match old non-SEO/SEF URIs to the new layout.

Assuming you actually have incoming '/alpe-adria/*' URIs, you're not rewriting the original URL into `/alpe-adria/art-culture`. You're using .htaccess to rewrite `/alpe-adria/art-culture` (coming in from a browser) into the original format that PHP and the server can digest. Please use the correct terminology. .htaccess does nothing to *outbound* URIs.

You're saying that `/alpe-adria/` is fixed, and you have a 'search engine friendly' group name (e.g., 'art-culture'). You want to map 'art-culture' into a URI for index.php? I can't see where you are getting the **grp** and **level** entries from in the incoming URI. The best you're going to be able to do is to have a number of lookup entries: match 'art-culture', output the desired full URI. Match something else, output the different desired full URI.